# Entr not restarting server

Tags: go, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to do something very simple: Restart my go server whenever any of the *.go files change. I did this:

```
find . -name "*.go" | entr -r -s 'sudo go run main.go'
```

The server starts all right first time (sudo does not require password). But 
later on when any of the files in sub directories change, entr is not restarting the server.
What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I found that if I run server on 8080 then the above command works as expected. However if I use a SSL certificate and listen on 443 (hence the sudo) then the command does not work.

Comment: Isn't -r supposed to wait till the current process exists ?

Comment: Ctrl+Z returns to terminal. Then I do netstat -tulpn | grep :443 and kill the process.